# Magento Payment Bridge Troubles

Tags: magento-1, payment

Has anyone had any success setting up MPB? I was trying to no avail to set it up and it appears to be all set up properly but when trying to access authorize.net the error message comes up `This payment method not available at this time...`

This is what comes through the IFrame, although when the Iframe is turned off then Auth.net works perfectly.

Comment: I have set up Payment Bridge successfully a few times.  What do you get when you run: php tools/merchant.php -i yourmerchantcode?

Comment: php tools/merchant.php: "This payment method is currently unavailable. If you would like to buy using this payment method, please contact us." This is MPB 1.11.18.0 and of course there is no real documentation yet. (The database was previously setup using MPB 1.0)

Comment: When you set up the MPB 1.11.18 did you completely re-do the config file or keep the old one?  The reason I ask is that there are new settings in the newer version.

Comment: Yes we are using a new config file.

Comment: Can you summarize all of your settings and post them here?  You can blank out any sensitive data of course, but if you could post the output from the PaymentBridge settings for your gateway then I may be able to help.

Comment: UPDATE: MPB is now connected but when trying to submit an order we get this error in the admin: Order saving error: Decoding failed: Syntax error

Comment: Disable magic_quotes from your system.  It's probably messing with the JSON response.  In your .htaccess try this: php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

Comment: its already off.

Comment: That error originates in the decode function in Zend/Json so I thought that may be the cause.  Is it possible that you have a space or special character before or after one of your settings in your PB config?  It may be worth re-entering all of your configuration settings in the bridge and ensure that you have nothing like that in there.

Comment: Checked and there are no spaces or special characters on the beginning or end of any of the settings in Magento of in the PB config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help!

It appears the host forgot to add some IP's to cfg/allowedips.php in our PB installation. This fixed it right away.

Now I am testing and learning how to use it.